# Multiple Object Sets Per Type are not supported? -

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have recently upgraded EF via nuget but now when my code is going to access the Logs object set it throws the exception above..

The error states that the object set Logs and Fulfillment.Model.IUnitOfWork.Logs' can both contain instances of type 'Fulfillment.Model.Log'.

I recently installed hangfire with ninject and am wondering if that had something to do with it?

Here is my datacontext/uow

```
 public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    IDbSet<Log> Logs { get; }
    IDbSet<Order> Orders { get; }
    void Commit();
}

public partial class FulfillmentEntities : DbContext, IUnitOfWork
{
    public FulfillmentEntities()
        : base("name=FulfillmentEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public DbSet<Log> Logs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }

    IDbSet<Log> IUnitOfWork.Logs
    {
        get { return Logs; }
    }

    void IUnitOfWork.Commit() {
        SaveChanges();
    }

    IDbSet<Order> IUnitOfWork.Orders
    {
        get { return Orders; }
    }
}
```

}

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It would be useful to know old and upgraded versions of EF.

Comment: totally separate from the issuem but  DbContext is a unit of work.  I'm not understanding the value of your IUnitOfWork.

Answer (score 2):

You have `Logs` being exposed twice:

```
public DbSet<Log> Logs { get; set; }

IDbSet<Log> IUnitOfWork.Logs
{
    get { return Logs; }
}
```

(and same issue with `Orders`)

Try changing your code to:

```
public partial class FulfillmentEntities : DbContext, IUnitOfWork
{
    public FulfillmentEntities()
        : base("name=FulfillmentEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public IDbSet<Log> Logs { get; set; }

    public IDbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }


    public void Commit()
    {
        SaveChanges();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply!

There must be more to it as the code is over 800 days old and after the upgrade the OnModelCreatingMethod is also getting called and the UnintentionalCodeFirstException is being thrown...

Any suggestions on how to simplify it somewhat? It was originally generating via a tt template

Comment: from what version did you upgrade, what what is the new version?

Comment: Hi I upgraded from 4 to 5

Comment: Hmm - are you using EDMX files?

Comment: I am indeed. I am using the out of the box edmx, tt files from 4 any tricks when upgrading there?